# Python Tkinter: Cannot insert text entry box in frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I cannot understand why my following tkinter script doesnt work properly. When I run it, I see it compiles with no errors, but I dont actually see any window open. The error occurs when I try to pack the text entry field. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk


main = Tk()
main.title('Testing')

topframe = Frame(main)
topframe.pack( side = TOP)

bottomframe = Frame(main)
bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )


frame = Frame(main)
frame.pack()

Label(topframe, text="Date").grid(row=0)
e1 = Entry(topframe)
e1.insert(1, "May 24, 2017")
e1.pack()
main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is an error when trying to run something like this.

```
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside .!frame which already has slaves managed by grid
```

You need to take care as to how you use your layout managers like `.pack, .grid, .place`. Check out this [link](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-geometry.htm) For info on the geometry manager.

change:

`Label(topframe, text="Date").grid(row=0)`

To:

`Label(topframe, text="Date").pack()`

And your program will run fine.

This works fine for me. Note at this point you don't need to import `ttk`

```
from Tkinter import *

main = Tk()
main.title('Testing')

topframe = Frame(main)
topframe.pack( side = TOP)

bottomframe = Frame(main)
bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )

frame = Frame(main)
frame.pack()

Label(topframe, text="Date").pack()
e1 = Entry(topframe)
e1.insert(1, "May 24, 2017")
e1.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

Results in:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All children of any one widget have to use the same geometry manager.  Specifically, your `topframe` has a Label using `.grid()`, and an Entry using `.pack()`; the two geometry managers will never be able to agree on a positioning of the widgets.  Change one of them to match the other, it's your choice which one to change (the fact that `topframe` was packed into its parent does not affect your choice here).